# Simplifying $\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$, is it possible?

Tags: factorial

Is it possible to simplify this equation?

Not looking for something long (that would defeat the purpose of simplifying)...

I'm doing some partial sums of sequences and was just wondering if I could simplify the equation before substituting n for {$1,2,3,...$}.

Comment: What is $\frac{n!}{n}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{n!}{2^n}$?

Comment: Sorry imranfat and Dave, I meant to say (n!)/(2n)!. The title has been changed.

Comment: Well, it's $\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n-1)(2n)}$, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Not quite... How did you derive your equation? It doesn't match the values for my equation when I sub in random numbers.

Comment: @jonathan, well, Rahul's fórmula is correct.

Comment: @Jonathan358 "*It doesn't match the values for my equation when I sub in random numbers*"  To make sure we are perfectly clear, by $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n-1)(2n)$ he means $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (n+i)$, i.e. the product of all $n$ of the integers from $n+1$ on up to $2n$.  E.g. for $n=4$ you have $\frac{n!}{(2n!)}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}=\frac{1}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}$.  Notice that $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4$ cancel from both the top and the bottom.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "simplify this equation"?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for clarifying JMoravitz and Rahul for providing the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's anything that's highly satisfying. As Rahul mentioned in the comments:
$$\frac{n!}{(2n)!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)... 3*2}{2n(2n-1)...n(n-1)...3*2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1)2n}$$

This is actually something called a falling factorial, defined as:
$$(a)_n = a(a-1)...(a-n+1)$$
So,
$$(2n)_n = 2n(2n-1)...(n+1)$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{n!}{(2n)!} = \frac{1}{(2n)_n}$$

Moreover,
$$\frac{1}{n!\binom{2n}{n}} =\frac{n!}{(2n)!} $$

You can also use the standard notation for Permutations to directly represent the quantity. However, all of these are really more of a way to condense the problem, not how to actually simplify it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!